# how to avoid parent activity going to onStop() when child activity is created?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a activity A which is a NativeActivity. It creates activity B. 
Now in my setup, I apply this theme to activity B.

```
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
```

Thus, when I create activity B which is transparent, it does not kill or make Activity A go to onStop() (out of focus).

Now I started to add code where Activity B creates activity C. Whats happening is that because of this, Activity A is going to onStop() (WHICH IS EXACTLY I DO NOT WANT !!). The only way to avoid this happening is applying the same transparent theme to activity C.

Can someone suggest me the correct solution that will avoid killing parent activity ?

Comment: I'm really not sure that you can. If your activity is not visible, the run-time will always call onStop. What is the pressing need for A to remain active? Would it be helpful for us to address that issue in a way that doesn't require A to remain active?

Comment: If Activity C is not transparent, what's the point of not stopping Activity A?

Answer (score 1):

here is an option but i dont know if it suits your needs, if you set theme for your activity C as dialog, your activity A will not call onStop(), because an activity will remain alive until you can see any part of it...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isnt the `onStop`, but the parent activity stopping (if you see what I mean).

Put this in your manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ..
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

i.e. set the launch mode (there's also `singleTop`). The parent activity will still be there, then just make onStop do what you want.